# codeigniter paypal url

Tags: codeigniter, paypal

I have downloaded the codeigniter paypal lib. I have few questions regarding this library.

1. My paypal url is set to this, $this->paypal_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr', Is it for testing!? How can I change it for actual transactions?!
2. My return url is set to a success controller, but I am not able to view the post information returned by paypal. Could anyone tell, what exactly is the problem?!
3. I want to store the transaction details (Amount paid,paid by whom, on what date and for which product), How exactly I can achieve this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of my answers relate to the Adaptive Payments API, so apologies if it doesn't correspond 1:1 but hopefully it will point you in the right direction.

1. The URL you're pointing to is the live site I believe, if you want to run api calls against the sandbox the proper URL is https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
2. The return URL is the page that Paypal redirects to after a transaction or cancel.  There is no POST request associated with this, however..you can pass parameters into the URL (such as http://mysite.com/succes.php?amount=xxx) so that you can retrieve them later.  This is a rather inconsistent way of doing things, though.  Which leads to...
3. Look up the IPN documentation on Paypal (starting point: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNIntro)  This allows you to specify a URL which Paypal will POST the transaction details to after a transaction request.

Before you can store these details you need to do send back a request to Paypal to validate that the IPN was generated from Paypal (this is in the docs).  After that you can store the details into your database.

Comment: but, when i am doing a transaction from the current paypal url ..it says ..its a test transaction... and the email is unregistered